# Creating a folder with the hostname inside Windows Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, group-policy

I'm trying to setup PowerShell transcription logging on Windows systems in our network and want to save the contents in folder names which list the system name. However, it appears that when creating a folder name it uses the literal value and doesn't accept potential variables used to get the system name.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a folder in Group Policy or Windows Explorer by using an environment variable to retrieve the system name?

I've tried using some common environment variables as shown in the screenshots. ( %COMPUTERNAME%, $hostname, ENV:COMPUTERNAME ENV:%COMPUTERNAME% ) However, the results end up with the literal name of the variable instead of the name of the computer system.

Comment: If it's on the local system, _why_ does it need to also reference itself in the path?